# Text Box style problem

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

We have a text box in a web page, which is used to modify the ip address. The text box style changes to the second box after editing the content in it. How can I change the style back to the style of the first text box? We are using javascript in the client side. The web client is Internet Explorer 7.

[image]

The code snippet in ASP page which creates the text box is given below

```
<td style="height: 27px"><input type="text" id="txtIpAddressHost" name="txtIpAddressHost" value="" onchange="ValidateParameter(this);" onkeydown="this.style.backgroundColor='white'"  disabled="disabled" maxlength="15" /></td>
```

The html before and after the changes are given below

Before Keypress

```
<input type="text" onkeydown="this.style.backgroundColor='white'" onchange="Validate(this);" maxlength="10" value="-30.000000" name="txtCoolSetPointCkt1" id="txtCoolSetPointCkt1">
```

After Keypress

```
<input type="text" onkeydown="this.style.backgroundColor='white'" onchange="Validate(this);" maxlength="10" value="-30.000000" name="txtCoolSetPointCkt1" id="txtCoolSetPointCkt1" style="background-color: white;">
```

css change

```
css change
{

    background-color: white;

}
```

Comment: Are you using CSS to set the style of the page? How does it change? Does the name of the field change, and therefore the CSS style it uses? Does it also happen on other browers? Code snippets of the problematic HTML would be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with CSS 2 you can achieve this only with CSS. Lets assume textbox has class ip-box.

```
    input.ip-box { border:1px solid #333; }
    //and when the input box has focus repeat the above rule
    input.ip-box:focus { border:1px solid #333; }
```

But ie7 doesn't support this pseudo class. In that case you can do with javascript like

```
    <input type="text" value="10.0.0.88" onfocus="javascript:this.style.border='1px solid #333' "/>
```

Comment: should mention the onblur event as well

Comment: this is just the snippets to give the idea. The point is apply the same style throughout. i.e. default, onfocus and yes you can add onblur too.